# Best practices for localizing WordPress content?

Tags: content, multi-language, customization

A client asked for a blog that will have localized content (i.e. en.blogname.com for English content, fr.blogname.com for French content, etc). Being new to building such a blog, we recently discovered [WPML](http://wpml.org/) and [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/), which look perfect for our needs.

Do you have any best / recommended practices for setting up a multilingual blog?

At this point, we don't envision the need to have the WordPress software translated, but if you've found that to be a good idea, we would love to know. The authors will all be multilingual (English + one other language), but it's conceivable that non-English speakers may be hired later.

Comment: *@Mike Lee:* I'm anxious to learn the answer too. I might have a new client who needs this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is without plugin - i set WP3.0 with multisite; the first blog is a dummy to rewrite the uesers to right blog with his language, a small script in the theme to rewirte ro the right language; i see in the browser-language of the users and rewrite; the second is the default blog, the third blog is another blog and so on - olso it is possible to swich the blog from post tot post with core function of WPMU and you can add own functions to post draft in other blogs from published post in a blog

**update** for your question:

*Sorry, my english is bad*

I install wp3.0 or MU and the first blog, the admin-blog has an small theme, one template with a small function. The function read the browser-language of the users on the frontend of the domain and sitch then to the other blog of this install, she have this language as default.

All other blogs are for different languages and one blog is for one language. 
So it is possible to has great tables for the different posts and all works with WP core methods. WPMU has enough function to switch from post to post in different language. Give it a post in blog english and link to post in blog german, than i write this with an own plugin in the postmeta of the post. So it is possible for the users, he can switch on the frontend from a post in other language. Also you can use `wp_insert_post()` to add an draft in blog german maybe, when you publish in blog english.

I hope you understand my way - works great and i have many customer with this solution.

### *Update, pulled from the comments 12/22/2012*

> We have created a free plugin to do this:
>   [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press)
>   *bueltge Dec 22 '11*

Comment: @bueltge Can you please describe your method in more detail?

Comment: maybe, my english is bad

Comment: i have wirte in my answer, the comment has not so much strings.

Comment: Excellent and flexible way. Vielen Dank Frank!

Comment: Thanks hakre! - i love your great content from blog and mails via wp-hackers

Comment: So to clarify, this does not recommend 'no plugin' but instead tells people to write their own plugin to patch together different sites within an MS installation.

Comment: Also: I use the same method in terms of writing my own plugin, which is awful. Someone needs to write a 3.0-inspired plugin that does what your plugin does with multiple sites and release it. I think it would be popular if it was as good as wpml/qtranslate but taking your proposed approach (which keeps each site database pure in case the plugin stops working later)

Comment: @bueltge, this is great feedback, thank you! I hadn't considered using multisite for this.

Comment: @Jeremy, I second your motion that someone needs to write such a plugin. After our project, we may consider abstracting what we've written, though that won't be for a while. If someone else goes for it first, I'd love to give it a spin. Thanks!

Comment: The most functions with my solution is possible with the core-functions of WP, it is not necessary to write a plugin. Maybe it is usefull when you use wp_insert_post() to add a draft in the second blog, when you publish a post - this is only necassary, when you will linked all posts in all languages.

Comment: Now a update: we have create a free plugin to do this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/

Comment: amazing Q/A and simply *wow* for this last comment, you are da man, @bueltge

Answer (score 3):

I have used qTranslate as well with success and seen it implemented in couple of blogs.

but the problem with using any of the 2 plugins is that with the wordpress updates, you have to wait for the new releases of plugins versions then update.
With other plugins, like a contact form, rating system or stuff like this , you can disable them temporary, find another replacement, but for something as important as this, you can not afford to do so.

so it is kinda tricky on the long run to use any of the 2 plugins to manage the main component of your blog aka your content and security concerns could arise.

That is why i support bueltge's method, try to implement it and good luck with that :)

Comment: Thanks for that background info. The problems with using plugins for this core feature is a great insight.