# Translate widget titles using qTranslate plugin

Tags: widgets, sidebar, title, translation, plugin-qtranslate

I'm actually using the qTranslate plugin to translate my website. It works really well with everything except one thing. the titles of my sidebar widgets.

Actually, to translate some words we need to put tags like this:

```
<!--:en-->My English Title<!--:--><!--:fr-->My French Title<!--:-->
```

When I use this in the content of my widget it works well. But in the title when I save the widget. It actually remove my tags and just displays:

```
My English TitleMy French Title
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There's been **years** since I last worked with xLanguage... Just checking it now and it hasn't been updated since **2009-06-09**! Searching in the backups cannot find an example on how to deal with this... IMHO, painful as it may be, you should plan a plugin migration ASAP :(

Comment: What plugin do you suggest?

Comment: Take a look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51803/12615

Comment: Sorry I was actually already using qTranslate and my problem was with qTranslate and not xLanguage... I'm gonna edit the question and give the answer

Comment: Well, that's a misspell..!

Comment: I actually tried them both at the same time so I was confusing about the one I used...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found the answer and instead of putting this in the Title:

```
<!--:en-->My English Title<!--:--><!--:fr-->My French Title<!--:-->
```

We need to put this code:

```
[:en]My English Title[:fr]My French Title
```

and qTranslate does the rest :)

Comment: A few years later, it should be `[:en]My English Title[:fr]My French Title[:]`, with a closing "tag"