# How to Translate Contact Form 7 using qTranslate?

Tags: translation, plugin-contact-form-7, plugin-qtranslate

I'm using [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) for my forms and also [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) to translate my website.

I would like to translate all my fields and for that I used:

```
<!--:en-->First Name (required)<!--:--><!--:ru-->Фамилия (обязательно)<!--:-->
```

But it display this:

```
First Name (required)Фамилия (обязательно)
```

What should I use to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I normally do when using this combination of plugins is to create *one form* per language.
Easy and effective.

You could also try qTranslate [quicktags](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3&sid=8c2eacd7f76f9a7bd320332ddec96c63&start=10): `[:en]English text[:ru]Фамилия`.
But much probably this will lead to some issues down the road.

Comment: Oh, I see that you [already know](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69807/12615) the quicktags... ;)

Comment: Yes, I tried with quiktags and it does not work. It just displays the quicktags like this. `[:en]First Name (required)[:ru]Фамилия (обязательно)` I think that creating 2 forms is the best solution. (Or maybe the only one)