# Two language versions for each article

Tags: multi-language, localization

I have a Wordpress website that needs to be available in two different languages. We have the articles written in both languages already.

I've seen a lot of solutions providing automatic translations but this won't work in this situation because we have to use translations produced by government approved translators.

What would be a good solution to allow each article to have 2 versions and allow switching between them with a button or dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

I think and use the way about an WP Multisite install, see [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content/1589#1589), background, information and benefit on a older question.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress does not have multilanguage capabilities out of the box. You will need to use a plugin like WPML or CMSwithTMS. These plugins will add the capability to publish translated versions of a page/post.