# multi-language WordPress site

Tags: multi-language

I am making multi-language site powered by WordPress.

[WPML](http://wpml.org/) is not free and it makes too many extra sql queries to database so it is not good solution for my site.

[qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) saves all languages in one database row and it is very complicated to move to another multi-language plugin later.

```
<?php _e( '<!--:en-->english text<!--:--><!--:de-->german text<!--:-->' ); ?>
```

[xLanguage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xlanguage/) hasn't been updated in over 2 years.

Is there any other **plugin to manage multi-language site**?

I have an idea to install [WordPress as multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) **and each language will have its own site**. Is it good practice?

[image]

Comment: Wordpress was just not made for such types of websites. Use a more powerful CMS instead. Using the multi-site feature doesn't sound very good to me either, because the pages are not linked to each other across the languages. For example, if you had created a page in French, it also should occur in the backend as template for English and German. I can't think of an easy way to accomplish that in Wordpress, whereas other CMS, like MODx or TYOP3 do have such a feature included by default.

Comment: @feela, TYOP what? Probably a typo ;) And it's WordPress, not Wordpress... webvitaly, yes, Multisite is a good way to go without gTrans or WPML complications (for some reason or another). Frank Bueltge answer bellow will lead to a very good plugin, for which he's one of the authors; excellent team behind it, IMO. And as he says, this has been [extensively discussed here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-language). All my multi-lingual sites are in gTrans or WPML, the next surely will be with MP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i set up my wordpress site as a wordpress multisite and then used "[multisite language switcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/)" plugin...
it is free and works great...

Comment: Interesting, but what plugin is this? I miss the link and the description of it. Check the [How to Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) guide, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This topic was often here in the questions; maybe you use the search before you ask. Also the topic to use WP MU to localize the content; see this [popular question and answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content/1589#1589); maybe it help you and you find also a plugin for localization with MU.

Answer (score 1):

I use WPML in combination with a Caching Plugin for my multilanguage-sites.

It is not free, i know, but the few bucks it costs are a lot less than actually developing your own stuff in this area.

The Problem with Multisite for Multilanguage is that you have to build the whole content on each Site. Images etc.. Also, you do not have the correlation between an article in English and it's translations.

So, I do not want to advertise Premium Plugins, but your best way of dealing with this is sticking to WPML and using W3 Total Cache or Supercache to enhance the performance.

Comment: I'd definetly go with WPML. Because of their support (paid product), it's simplicity and you can also roll that cost to your clients if that's what concerns you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use WPML but scanned their site and it seems to me that if I would have needed a plugin for that, I would have gave it a try, but ..... why do you need a plugin at all? Using network installation is my recomandation whenever anybody bothers to ask me.

For the price of having some extra administration overhead you get total flexibility for each locale.
On the other hand WPML is not perfect and you might run into plugin and theme compatability issues.

Maybe someone here that use WPML can explain what use case/workflow does WPML handle better then network installation for him.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use multisite than WPML. WPML slows down website a lot. With multisite you dont have connected posts with translation, but gives you much faster loading.