# How to manage multiple domain with different languages on each domain with single wordpress installation?

Tags: multisite, multi-language, domain-mapping

I need to manage multiple domain with different content on each domain. For each domain I need to manage content in different languages. I found we can use [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)
to manage different domain with single wp installation. But my concern is can the contents be managed with multi language for each domain. Has anyone done this kind of task before. Please advice.

How the plugin mentioned above can be tested in local server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But my concern is can the contents be managed with multi language for each domain" Not very clear what you are asking here.  WPMU manages content in multiple languages...that's what it is designed to do.

Comment: @JCL1178 Thanks for your reply. I have not installed and tested yet MU Domain mapping plugin :). I wanted to know whether WPMU works with MU Domain mapping plugin or not before I start working on the site.

Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I got my plugins confused. You should be looking at WPML (WordPress Multi-Language) in conjunction with WPMU  Mapping

Comment: Please, *specify exactly* what do you mean by: `1)` **Single WP Installation**, as you tagged this as [tag:multisite] and that plugin ONLY runs on Multisite (old WPMU). `2)` What do you understand by **multi-language**? Each site with one language, or each site with *many languages*?.

Answer (score 1):

Use a default Multisite installation and enhance this with the plugin MLP - [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/).

You find a lot of information in [this post](http://marketpress.com/2013/multilingual-wordpress/), a better english as my.

You find the idea and discussion about this solid solution, benefits in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content/1589#1589) from my side to the same question in WPSE.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The essential parts are inside the link to an other answer from WPSE, maybe this is stable enough for this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a different language in each domain, and assuming your content is different, you just need your locale setting set differently for each site in your multi-site settings.

This will make sure that the proper .po/.mo files are loaded for each different settings.

In Transposh (the plugin that I have written) this actually happens, and locale can be set for each sub domain by selecting a different default language in the settings for each site. (I used it to allow my kid to have the management interface in the local language instead of English)

If you are looking to manage the same content for different domains, this solution isn't really relevant.

Good luck